# Getting the throwing function's locals in the unhandled exception handler

Tags: java, android

If one sets up an unhandled exception handler using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in a Java Android app, can one capture the local state of the throwing function in the handler? Ideally, local state of the intermediate functions that lead up to the point of throw would be nice also.

If not, is there by any chance a native (JNI or similar) hook to that effect?

Surely I'm not the only one who is looking for actionable intelligence from uncaught runtime crashes.

Putting a try/catch midstack may not be an option, 'cause sometimes exceptions that can be (potentially) tracked back to app bugs happen in all system code stacks.